# AABB - AABB Collision response (sliding)

Tags: c++, math, collision-detection

[image]

**Here is the situation**:

- I have a room with objects inside
- Each object has it's own AABB

**Here is what i do**:

- I check for collision between objects by checking AABB-AABB intersections

**Here is what i need**:

- How do i calculate the 'sliding' / response between those AABBs?

Comment: The player will slide as if the object was a box, even if the object is some other shape?

Comment: How about using a 3D physics engine? May be easier than to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Can I direct you to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ? I think that the chances to find an answer on your question may be larger there

Comment: @Gorgen, this is what i'll do.

Comment: @Constantinius - i don't want to link a complex physics engine to calculate simple things in this game.